# Dropdown doesn't work in angular using semantic ui

Tags: html, angular, semantic-ui

Dropdown doesn't display items. Please see the below source code.

```
<div class = "ui centered grid">
  <div class = "ten wide column">
    <form class = "ui form">
      <h4 class = "ui dividing header">Personal details</h4>
      <div class = "field">
        <label>Name</label>
        <div class = "two fields">
          <div class = "field">
            <input type= "text" name="firstName" placeholder="First name">
          </div>
          <div class = "field">
            <input type= "text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last name">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class = "two fields">
          <div class = "field">
            <input type= "text" name="fathersName" placeholder="Father's name">
          </div>
          <div class = "field">
            <input type= "text" name="mothersName" placeholder="Mother's name">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class = "two fields">
          <div class = "field">
            <input type= "text" name="displayName" placeholder="Display name">
          </div>
          <div class = "field">
            <input type= "text" name="mobileNumber" placeholder="Mobile number">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class = "two fields">
          <div class = "field">
            <input type= "text" name="birthDate" placeholder="Birth date">
          </div>
          <div class = "field">
              <div class = "ui selection dropdown">
                  <input type="hidden" name = "gender">
                  <i class = "dropdown icon"></i>
                  <div class = "default text">Gender</div>
                  <div class = "menu">
                      <div class = "item" data-value = "male">Male</div>
                      <div class = "item" data-value = "female">Female</div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <h4 class = "ui dividing header">Native details</h4>

    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

When I click on gender it doesn't display anything.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a regular `select`?

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="gender">
  <option value="male">Male</option>
  <option value="female">Female</option>
</select>
```